# Azure DevOps Azure SQL DacpacTask SQL72018 Permission Could Not Be Imported

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, dacpac

We have a release pipeline in Azure DevOps that deploys a database project to our Azure SQL Database via the Azure SQL Dacpac Task. Everything has been working fine but suddenly yesterday the pipeline started failing with the following error:

```
##[error]*** An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue.
##[error]Error SQL72018: Permission could not be imported but one or more of these objects exist in your source.
```

As far as I know, nothing has changed on the database side or in the pipeline. We also ruled out that it could be an issue with the specific dacpac file because previously successful releases now fail with the same error.

I searched extensively for the SQL72018 error, but didn't really find any answers as to what would be causing that so am wondering if there was some Azure DevOps task update or something that we could be missing?

Not sure what would have caused this to break out of nowhere like that.

It does work if we add the `p:/ignorePermissions=true` parameter to the task, but we have never needed that before this.

**UPDATE:**

Wanted to update this as I was able to gather a little more information by adding the `/Diagnostics:True` parameter to the pipeline task in order to print out Diagnostic info from SQLPackage.

When I added that, I also see this error:

*Microsoft.Data.Tools.Diagnostics.Tracer Error: 1 : 2022-04-05T08:38:37 : Error detected when reverse engineering the database. Severity:'Warning' Prefix:'' Error Code:'0' Message:The permission 'VDP ' was not recognized and was not imported.  If this problem persists, contact customer support.*

So it looks like some "VDP" permission is what is causing the issue, but we don't know what that permission is for or where it came from as it's not in the database project.

Comment: Maybe something related to requiring TLS 1.2 that was implemented recently.  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/azure-devops-requires-tls-1-2-on-all-connections-including-visual-studio/

Comment: @Matt - I did initially wonder that as well because the timing seems suspicious. However I followed the TLS compatibility check from this site (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/deprecating-weak-cryptographic-standards-tls-1-0-and-1-1-in-azure-devops-services/#quick-check-of-tls-1-2-compatibility) on our build server and things seemed to work so I don't believe that's the issue unless there is something else I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We finally got to the bottom of this. It turns out a new permission was added to the database the day before the pipeline started to fail. The database permission that caused the issue was `VIEW DATABASE PERFORMANCE STATE`. That was the `VDP` permission that SQLPackage.exe was complaining about.

Unsure why that particular permission caused the error as we manage all of our database permissions outside of the database project, so not sure why other permissions wouldn't have caused issues prior to this one.

Since we are managing permissions outside of our database project, the resolution was to add the `p:/ignorePermissions=true` [SQLPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver15) parameter to the pipeline permanently. This was confirmed as the appropriate solution by a Microsoft representative after we put a ticket in.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a spurious/orphan permission in your target database - as mentioned in this post [How could our database be causing SqlPackage to fail? (SQL72018)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093004/how-could-our-database-be-causing-sqlpackage-to-fail-sql72018).

Comment: Any thoughts as to what kind of permissions that would be? Like SQL roles? Reason I ask is because we don't really control any permissions through the database project; it's mostly all just creation of tables, views and stored procs. So I'm not really sure what to look into there.

Comment: I suggest - go to your target database and see roles, users and permissions present and not in your dacpac - you can also export the database to dacpac and then compare them

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is there something particular to look for? We control permissions outside of the project, so the comparison does show permissions that are not in the source (dacpac) but that are in the target (Azure DB). However, those would have always been like that so not sure if there's something specific. It looks like that other related answer the trigger itself was bad so not sure what would be bad with the permissions.

Comment: ha ha - if you control the permission externally from dacpac then it will always complain about them not present in DACPAC - you will need to use the flag you are using already.

Comment: Well that's interesting because we've had this project and pipeline for several years and always controlled permissions outside of it from the beginning. We never saw any errors like this until the last week. Thanks for the info though, we may look more into using that parameter permanently.